# Is there something wrong with my mod_rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

to change what the user sees as:

```
example.com/hello/world
```

to what the server sees as:

```
example.com/index.php?slug=hello/world
```

But it doesn't work. I know the .htaccess itself is working because I have tried other, simpler rules that I've used elsewhere ans they work fine. Is there something wrong with this one?

Thank you!

Comment: What doesn't work properly? Do you get a rewrite loop? (looks like a rewrite loop on index.php)

Comment: Do you have `RewriteCond` to prevent the rule from working on existing files/dirs like index.php?

Comment: @Michael Err, no I don't. That seems like it could be it! Do you know how I would do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't process the rule if the file or directory actually exists. This will prevent the rule from acting on `index.php` and causing a rewrite loop.  It will also prevent it from affecting your static content (css, js, images).

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note, per comments, `[QSA]` is added to ensure that the existing query string parameters are preserved across the rewrite.

Comment: You should also add the QSA parameter, like `[L,QSA]`